# Why is Chrome making me declare my variable in this loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, vue.js

This behavior is weird. I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
myObjects = [
  { 
    name: 'List 1', 
    invitations: [
      { email: 'ralph@ralph.com', stamp: '1234' },
      { email: 'mike@mike.com', stamp: '4576' }
    ]
  },
  { 
    name: 'List 2', 
    invitations: [
      { email: 'steve@steve.com', stamp: '5678' },
      { email: 'bob@bob.com', stamp: '6789' }
    ]
  },
]
```

I need to filter the objects where the invitations array includes a certain email address, so I'm doing this, which works great when I test it in Sublime Text:

```
filteredObjects = myObjects.filter(obj => { 
  for (invitation of obj.invitations) {
    if (invitation.email == 'bob@bob.com') return true;
  }
});

// [ { name: 'List 2', invitations: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

However, if I try to run this in Chrome, it's making me declare the variable in the for loop for some reason (note the added "var" in the for loop):

```
filteredObjects = myObjects.filter(obj => { 
  for (var invitation of obj.invitations) {
    if (invitation.email == 'bob@bob.com') return true;
  }
});
```

If I don't declare the variable (with "var"), I get an error in my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: invitation is not defined
```

I want to understand why this is happening, and if perhaps there's a better way to write my filter.

Comment: If you do not  declare `invitation`, what does it refer to?

Comment: do you have use strict somewhere?

Comment: Are you asking if there is another variable with the same name in global scope? There isn't, and I've tried a few random variable names to make sure it wasn't a collision issue.

Comment: @Alan: If `use strict` is in force, variables *must* be declared with `var`  (or `let`, or `const`) before use. `for (let invitation of obj.invitations) {` would get you minimally scoped name.

Comment: @dgrogan I'm using Vue.js but as far as I know it does not use strict mode. I've used for loops elsewhere without declarations and they work fine.

Comment: Whatever caused it, you should always declare your variables with `let` or `var` before using them. From the error message I would guess that you passed your code through a minifier/uglifier.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I am indeed using webpack, how can you tell from the error?

Comment: @Alan Sometimes it gets messed up if you don't declare your variables properly. Make it a habit and save yourself future possible headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Chrome is forcing you to declare the variable `invitation`, then that's because it is preventing implicit or accidental global variables and that's because your code is in a section that Chrome considers `strict` mode.  You would have to show us the larger code context for us to discern exactly why it is treating the code as `strict` mode.

There are some implementations of browsers (early versions of arrow functions in Firefox, for example) that made arrow function bodies automatically in `strict` mode, though that is not part of the standard.  Or, this larger code context your filter statement is in may be in strict mode for some other reason.

This is a very good thing.   All variables should be expressly declared in the intended scope.  Letting you write code with accidental, implicit or automatic globals is a recipe for accidentally creating and using conflicting global variables.  It creates hard to track down bugs that may even be intermittent in behavior (especially if involved in asynchronous operations).

Strict mode will be automatically enforced:

1. Anywhere the code is manually declared to be `strict` mode with `'use strict';` at the top of function scope.
2. Methods declared with ES6 `Class` syntax are automatically in `strict` mode.

You can see a full listing of the effects of strict mode in [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and [this article on using `Class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: Thank you. After reviewing some of the comments above, I have determined that it is likely something happening in webpack during bundling because if you copy and paste the code directly into the Chrome console, it works fine without the declaration. However, webpack may be doing something that triggers strict mode in Chrome, and then when it gets to that undeclared variable, it's giving me an error. Lesson learned. Always declare.

Comment: @Alan - That sounds likely.  Code generators like to run their code in strict mode because it more precisely follows strict rules.  You could look at the generated code and probably see exactly what is causing it or just go with that as the conclusion.